# Is there a simple JavaScript plugin that can let users click on a Google map (or drag an icon), and then alert the lat/long?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want people to easily click the embedded map, and then the la/long gets alerted.

Comment: 21k rep and this question? Strange.

Comment: @FDL: It was asked 3 years and half ago!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps API, the simplest example I could come up with.  ([edited a google example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html))

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Maps API</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.onload = function() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
      alert(e.latLng.lat() + ', ' + e.latLng.lng());
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Google Maps.

Comment: How? Is there a link or example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

I suggest you have a closer look at [this page (Latitude and Longitude of a Point)](http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html) and especially the underlying javascript (inspect the source).

You can aslo check ou[t this helpfull thread.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=42036fb0e3ffdcfc&hl=en)